# Pass UIButton object name to a function

Tags: ios, swift, function, object, uibutton

How do I pass UIButton object name to a function to change a button image? Or is there another way to resolve this?

I call my function like this (without the object name).

How do I change it to pass the UIButton object name also to the function?

```
flipImage(imageName: "myImage1")
```

My function:

```
func flipImage(imageName: String) {
    //  self.Picture.image = UIImage (named: imageName)
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    btn1.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    UIView.transition(with: btn1, duration: 0.3, options:  .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)
}
```

I've changed the function to this. There are "no errors" but how do I call the function if this is the correct way?

```
func flipImage2(buttonName: UIButton, imageName: String) {
    //  self.Picture.image = UIImage (named: imageName)
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    buttonName.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    UIView.transition(with: buttonName, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the button name"? Your second function passes a button instance, which is correct. How do you determine which button you want to change the image for?

Comment: ok. its like this. I call this function from a timer to change images on several uiButtons... and it would be much easier if I also could pass button name to the function. so pass BOTH buttonName: AND inameName and use in the function

Comment: Ok, well, you could keep,your buttons in an array and then when the timer fired you could loop,over the array, calling your function for each element of the array.

Comment: question remains... how would the function call look like? if this works for only imageName? flipImage(imageName: "myImage1") I want to add the buttonName also in the function? thats the question if that is possible. sounds like there should be a way to get it done somehow.... like the function -> flipImage2 ..... how do I call it with also the buttinName included

Comment: It looks exactly like `flipImage2`. You don't pass a button "name" you just pass a reference to the `UIButton` instance that you want to  change

Answer (score 0):

> how do I pass uiButton object name to a function to change a button
>   image? or is there another way to resolve this?

Wait ,do you want a custom UiButton that looks different than the normal UiButton ? so you do have a custom image for that button right ? I would suggest you this video

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAU3VE7T21M&t=217s
```

the method in this video is good (if I got your question right of course and it uses the storyboard)
Basically what it does is :

1. Put the image you want inside the UiView
2. Set the constraints
3. Add a UiGestureRecogniser to the image
4. Set "user interaction" to true (on the right side of the story board)
5. You'll be able to link your image as an @IBAction and link the image to an @IbOutlet (or you wont be able to change it later)

By adding an @IBAction to your image , you can actually change the image after your defined gesture is recognized
Assuming that you watched the video, this the end you shoud be getting something in your code like

```
 @IBAction func nameOfYourFunction (_ sender: Any) {
     ...   }
```

then what you do is just adding your code inside 
so it should look like

```
@IBAction func nameOfYourFunction (_ sender: Any) 
{
  yourImageName.image = UIImage(named: "yourNewImageName")
 // done 
}
```

now let's say you want to change the image every time you click on the button then you need a boolean value....
do it like this (after watching the video)

```
import UIKit
var isTwitterSelected = false // this will be switched every time later in the code (when you'll be pressing the button)
@IBAction func shareOnTwitterPressed (_ sender: Any)
    {
        isTwitterSelected = !isTwitterSelected
        twitterShareButton.image  = isTwitterSelected ? UIImage(named: "twitter") : UIImage(named: "twitterUnSelected")
        print("pressed twitter share button ")
    }
```

hope I was able to help you, if not then I'm sorry

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: ow yeah thank you; this is my first comment. I'll try to edit my post then